# MM/dd/yyyy date format gives incorrect date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, java-time

I am providing a date input in MM/dd/yyyy format, the format produces an incorrect date on UI, this only happens with MM/dd/yyyy format, however, it is working fine if input will be in dd/MM/yyyy.

eg: if today's date 04/08/2020, then it is rendered as 07/09/2021, which is of course wrong date

The application using extjs3 as frontend and so the date picker.

```
 function insSKUDate(element,textElement,img){
        var selectHandler = function(myDP, date) {
            var field = document.getElementById(textElement);
            field.value = date.format('m/d/Y');
            field.text = date.format('m/d/Y');
            dateField = document.getElementById(textElement);
            myDP.hide();
        };
        var myDP = new Ext.DatePicker(
                {
                    startDay: 1,
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    listeners: {
                        'select':selectHandler
                    }
                }
        );
        var innerdata = document.getElementById(element);
        innerdata.innerHTML="";
        myDP.render(element);
        var clickHandler = function() {
            myDP.show();
        };

        Ext.EventManager.on(img.id, 'click', clickHandler);
    }
```

**somewhere in HTML form**

```
<td width="20%">
   <input type="text" class="textbox"
      value="<s:property value='skulaunchDate'/>"
      name="skulaunchDate"
      id="skulaunchDate" readonly="readonly"/>
   &nbsp;
   <img style="vertical-align:text-bottom" src="images/calimg.jpg"
      width="16" height="16"
      onClick="insSKUDate('skulaunchDateSpan', 'skulaunchDate', this)"
      id="skulaunchDateIcon"/>
   &nbsp;
   <span id="skulaunchDateSpan"
      style="position:absolute;z-index:1;width:50px;"></span>
   <div id="skulaunchDateErrorMsg" align="left"
      style="color:#FF0000"/>
</td>
```

**Somewhere in my Struts' execute()**

```
 public String getSkulaunchDate() {
    return skulaunchDate;
}


public void setSkulaunchDate(String skulaunchDate) {
    this.skulaunchDate = skulaunchDate;
}

            if (bean.getSkulaunchDate() != null)
               setSkulaunchDate(dateUtil.getSQLDateToString(bean.getSkulaunchDate(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));//Replace dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy
//               setSkulaunchDate(getSkuLaunchDateStrFormat(bean,dateUtil));//Replace dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy
                System.out.println("3.getSkulaunchDate----"+ getSkulaunchDate());
            setContactPersonName(bean.getContactPersonName());
            setContactPersonPosition(bean.getContactPersonPosition());
            setContactPersonEmail(bean.getContactPersonEmail());
            setContactPersonNumber(bean.getContactPersonNumber());
            setRemarks(bean.getRemarks());
            setTpRemarks(bean.getTpRemarks());

            try {
                if(request_bean.getRequestDate() != null){
                    setRequest_date(dateUtil.getUtilDateToString(request_bean.getRequestDate(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));//Replace dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getStackTrace());
            }
```

**I have doubt on the below method, but it looks fine**

```
public  String getSQLDateToString(java.sql.Date date, String format) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

It is found that the input is in SQL date having some problem while parsing, apart from this util date is working fine.
please suggest me the solution to rectify this.

Comment: Stop using `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, that's an outdated API. Use `java.time.LocalDate` for date-only operations and format it using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I am using java 7

Comment: OK, then there is a nice [backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to be used...

Comment: suggest me by keeping this approach as it is

Answer (score 0):

The legacy date-time API is known to be [confusing and error-prone](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since you are using Java-7, unfortunately, either you will have to live with it or you can backport the code using [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to Java-7 using [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

I recommend you address the following problems with your code:

1. Never use a date-time parsing/formatting API without a `Locale`.
2. If your method can not handle an exception (i.e. can not do something to recover from the failure), it should simply throw the exception so that the calling method can get an opportunity to handle it appropriately. Therefore, using `e.printStackTrace()` in your method, `getSQLDateToString` is a bad idea. By the way, [`SimpleDateFormat#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) does not throw an exception. Probably, you got confused with [`SimpleDateFormat#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) which throws `ParseException`.

The following code incorporates these comments:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Today
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println(getSQLDateToString(date, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
        System.out.println(getSQLDateToString(date, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }

    public static String getSQLDateToString(java.sql.Date date, String format) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
02/07/2021
07/02/2021
```

**Using the modern date-time API**

Use `java.sql.Date#toLocalDate` to convert a `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Today
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println(getSQLDateToString(date, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
        System.out.println(getSQLDateToString(date, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }

    public static String getSQLDateToString(java.sql.Date date, String format) {
        LocalDate localDate = date.toLocalDate();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return dtf.format(localDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
02/07/2021
07/02/2021
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.